# Publishing artifacts with sources on archiva

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2, archiva

At work I'm dipping my toes in managing project dependencies with maven. We use Apache Archiva (1.2.1) as a local repository and proxy. I'm adding artifact for open source project, that is not published on any public repository. I've learned that to publish the *sources* I should [use the Classifier field](http://osdir.com/ml/users-archiva-apache/2009-06/msg00029.html) on **Upload artifact** page. The sources are then listed alongside the jar and pom when I browse the repository.

But when I update my maven dependencies I get only the jar and pom from the repository. I noticed that sources are also missing when the archiva proxies for me the downloads from other public repositories. I didn't find any configuration options in Archiva's admin pages to serve the sources... What am I missing?

**Update**: I was missing the fact that artifact sources have to be downloaded manually. I.e. the maven client has to request them, which is controlled by command line option `-DdownloadSources=true`. Maven Integration for Eclipse has a preference setting to always download them as described in [Resolving artifact sources](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Resolving+artifact+sources). Archiva then serves the sources for local artifacts or proxies the request to remote repositories and caches the sources for future requests.

Comment: This solved a non-archiva problem for me.  Please add some tags to this question to make it easier to locate: maven jar source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archiva does serve the sources, but Maven does not request them by default. I know since I also use Archiva as my Maven repo. How are you requesting the sources?

If you're using eclipse

- you can run `mvn eclipse:eclipe -DdownloadSources=true` in the project directory;
- you can install the [Maven Integration for Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org).

Both of them should return the sources if they are available.

Comment: I am using the Maven Integration for Eclipse. When it installed artifacts from public repositories, they were downloaded with sources. From Archiva they come without sources. It least that's who I blame based on my observation... Same results from command line.

Does that mean I have to teach maven (in my settings.xml) to always request sources? How?

Comment: That's quite strange. Any error in the archiva.log file? What about requesting the source file manually - e.g. load in the browser $archiva/repo/internal/$groupId/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version-sources.jar ? (Not 100% of path)

Comment: Ahmm... I'm stupid. I did not realize, that I have to request the sources manually or change the preference in the preferences of Maven Integration for Eclipse. Then everything works. I was puzzled that some artifacts in my local repository included sources (for example junit, joda-time), without me ever specifying that manually. Maybe some archetype plugin did that for me...

Answer (score 0):

The sources aren't required to satisfy compile/runtime dependencies.  If you wanted to bundle sources with your app, then you would specify a dependency with a source.  Or you would use a plug in like assembly to grab them from archiva.